# ELK stack - metricbeat not working container

Tags: docker, elk, metricbeat

https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk#how-to-enable-the-provided-extensions

I am going through this to install the containerized ELK stack but cannot seem to make metricbeat work and dont know how to configure metric beat such that it shows on kibana.

```
docker-compose up setup
docker-compose up
```

then changed the password for elastic, kibana and logstash like follows

```
docker-compose exec elasticsearch bin/elasticsearch-reset-password --batch --user elastic
```

did that for all three and then I started it back up again

```
docker-compose up -d logstash kibana
```

I have now run `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f extensions/metricbeat/metricbeat-compose.yml up --remove-orphans -d metricbeat` and metricbeat is running, no ports are open and when I check my kibana, there is nothing showing for metricbeat on discover.